# Flutter Searchable Dropdown Search Problem

Tags: flutter

When I try to filter it is not searching correct.
problem just search (filter last value)

My git: https://github.com/YGRL/TesteSearchDropdown

font: https://pub.dev/packages/searchable_dropdown

[image]

Comment: I guess the problem is the that you are passing a object instance as value for the drop down item although is allowed in the searchable dropdown class, the search is done by the String representation of the value and not by 'instance.field' that you are looking for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You do not need to create you own `searchable_dropdown` 
override `toString` to let data contains both lower and upper case will work 
and you can search both upper and lower case

code snippet

```
@override
  String toString() {
    return '${v_n} ${v_id}'.toLowerCase() + ' ${v_n} ${v_id}'.toUpperCase();
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:searchable_dropdown/searchable_dropdown.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());




class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class VagasDisponivei {
  String v_n;
  String v_id;

  VagasDisponivei({this.v_n, this.v_id});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '${v_n} ${v_id}'.toLowerCase() + ' ${v_n} ${v_id}'.toUpperCase();
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<VagasDisponivei> _vagasDisponiveis;
  String vaga_name;
  VagasDisponivei selectedValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _vagasDisponiveis = [
      VagasDisponivei(v_id: "1", v_n: "A0001"),
      VagasDisponivei(v_id: "2", v_n: "A0002"),
      VagasDisponivei(v_id: "3", v_n: "A0003"),
      VagasDisponivei(v_id: "4", v_n: "A0004"),
      VagasDisponivei(v_id: "5", v_n: "A0005"),
      VagasDisponivei(v_id: "6", v_n: "A0006"),
      VagasDisponivei(v_id: "7", v_n: "A0007"),
      VagasDisponivei(v_id: "8", v_n: "A0008"),
      VagasDisponivei(v_id: "9", v_n: "A0009"),
      VagasDisponivei(v_id: "10", v_n: "A0010"),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('teste'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SearchableDropdown(
              hint: Text('Select'),
              items: _vagasDisponiveis.map((item) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<VagasDisponivei>(
                    child: Text(item.v_n), value: item);
              }).toList(),
              isExpanded: true,
              value: selectedValue,
              isCaseSensitiveSearch: true,
              searchHint: new Text(
                'Select ',
                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedValue = value;
                  print(selectedValue);
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that I need to put the text to display that no results were found, when the user enters invalid value, but it is not working it only searches the last value

Comment: package use contains, you can combine this long string to allow contains.

Comment: do you mean you copy paste run my example and still have error?

Comment: I adjusted some things now it's working

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it help. thanks.

Comment: @chunhunghan thanks .. its works for me

Comment: thanks ... this must be in repo...

Comment: SearchableDropdown is not working in latest stable release of flutter.. also SearchableDropdown's last updated is in 2020 so it's not null safety. So be careful before implementing this library..

Comment: @AdityaPatil is right. Consider using search_choices plugin as a maintained replacement.